# Using Java equivalent Reflection in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

There is one way to write abstract method in Java:

```
abstract public Class<? extends A> getAClass();
```

This will return any class that extends class "A".

Is there any way to achieve this in C#?

Comment: What is a purpose of making that method abstract? There is a built-in public final Class getClass() in java and getType() equivalent in C#

Comment: And one more thing - how you want to return 1 class definition in such model? You say ANY but return 1

Comment: actually the abstract method is like                                  abstract public  Class<? extends A> getAClass();

Comment: Still dont understand a purpose but in C# it will be:
abstract public Type getAClass<T>() where T:A
More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx

Comment: Cool, making it an official answer in that case :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
abstract public Type getAClass<T>() where T:A
```

More info - [where (generic type constraint) (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx)

Comment: what I want is this method should return any Type which is subclass of A. so if I use this method it should be like this              "Type obj= getAClass()";but here we need to pass argument for calling this method like "Type obj=getAClass<T>()" where T is derived class

Comment: can you edit your question with some example and class structure you plan to use?